# Regular expression to allow alpha, a few special characters or an empty string

Tags: regex

I have my regular expression that is validating a form field and allows only alpha and a few selected special characters. 
But this field is optional, so I need to make it allowing also empty strings.

My current regex `is /^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i`

I tried various solutions to add the empty string option, but nothing worked.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the `+` to `*`, which updates the meaning from 1+ repeats to 0+ repeats (essentially making it optional).

```
/^[a-z ,.'-]*$/i
            ^
```

Also, I suggest using `\s` instead of an empty space *if possible* since it makes more sense to someone used to reading regular expressions and you won't miss it at first glance. Please note that `\s` is shorthand for `[\r\n\t\f ]`, so it will also match newlines and tabs (i.e. it may not work for your scenario).

Comment: I just found something that worked on my situation... Still testing it though. I am going to try yours as well...

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I just sorted it out. This one seems to do the trick. If you see any flaw on it, please let me know.

```
/^$|[a-z ,.'-]+$/i
```

Comment: This does not work as you expect. RegEx does alternation (`|`) at a group level, so this is looking for `^$` OR `[a-z ,.'-]+$`..in other words you would need to add another `^` anchor after the `|`.

Comment: Also this will **not** be as efficient (by a small margin), since it will always match the beginning of the String, then fail trying to match the end of the String (assuming it has some content).  Then it has to *start over*, match the beginning of the string, and then check your character class.  My example will match the beginning of the String, and then optionally check the character class.